# Deploying existing AngularJS + Java application as a .war

Tags: java, angularjs, war

I have an AngularJS application, which follows some of the [advices](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) given by [John Papa](https://johnpapa.net/). The main point is that I used the [folder-by-feature architecture](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y152) in this application.

My application uses some controllers in order to treat data in Java. There are no beans nor services, as I do not need them in my particular context, there are just those controllers.

What I would like is to deploy this application and those controllers in a .war file, in order to put it on a Tomcat Server (probably Tomcat 7) and access the interface contained in my AngularJS application.

Do I need to keep Java and Angular separated in two resources, or can I fold them both in one .war file and still be able to use them correctly ?

I am new to complete application deployment, so any advices will be welcome.
Thanks in advance.

---

The project structure, basically, is just:

```
| src
  | main
    | java
      | controllers
        | JavaController1.java
        | JavaController2.java
      | config
        | (configuration files if needed)
    | webapp
      | bower_components
      | js
        | (directives, services, core)
      | features
        | feature1
          | feature1.html
          | feature1Controller.js
        | feature2
          | feature2.html
          | feature2Controller.js
      | css
      | (etc...)
```

Controllers are (at the moment) exposed via the @RestController annotation from [Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html), but if needed they could be exposed otherwise if needed.

Comment: Those controllers that you have in Java, are exposed via rest services or something like that? Could you share the general structure of the java code?

Comment: Edited the question, I don't know if that answers your question ?

Comment: Indeed. So, you want to have an index.html accesed by localhost:8080 I.E. After that you need to test your rest services using something like postman. Now in your index place all the angular application and reach the rest services using something like $resources or an ajax call. The rest services will be I.E under the localhost:8080/restServices/ path. Then you can use the rest services in angular hiting the restServices path. In the past I've work in a application with these technologies and I think there will be no problems doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can (probably should) put your java code and angular code in the same war.